# Comparing different objects

Tags: java, sorting

I have an abstract class called DrawingObject that is extended by four subclasses: Point, Line, FreeFormLine, and Circle. DrawingObject implements Comparable and I have defined the compareTo method to look like this

```
public int compareTo(DrawingObject object)
{
    if(object instanceof Point && this instanceof Point)
    {
        //determine which has a higher value
        return 0;
    }
    else if(object instanceof Point && this instanceof Line)
        return 1;
    else if(object instanceof Point && this instanceof FreeFormLine)
        return 1;
    else if(object instanceof Point && this instanceof Circle)
        return 1;

    else if(object instanceof Line && this instanceof Point)
        return -1;
    else if(object instanceof Line && this instanceof Line)
    {
        //determine which has a higher value
        return 0;
    }
    else if(object instanceof Line && this instanceof FreeFormLine)
        return 1;
    else if(object instanceof Line && this instanceof Circle)
        return 1;

    else if(object instanceof FreeFormLine && this instanceof Point)
        return -1;
    else if(object instanceof FreeFormLine && this instanceof Line)
        return -1;
    else if(object instanceof FreeFormLine && this instanceof FreeFormLine)
    {
        //determine which has a higher value
        return 0;
    }
    else if(object instanceof FreeFormLine && this instanceof Circle)
        return 1;

    else if(object instanceof Circle && this instanceof Point)
        return -1;
    else if(object instanceof Circle && this instanceof Line)
        return -1;
    else if(object instanceof Circle && this instanceof FreeFormLine)
        return -1;
    else if(object instanceof Circle && this instanceof Circle)
    {
        //determine which has a higher value
        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now that I have this I would like to extend the code the sorting by value. I am confused as how to go about doing this. For example Point has two instance fields, double x and double y. I am confused as to which to sort by. I am also in confusion over the other types of objects and how to sort them. Each class has an equals method that is declared abstract in DrawingObject but implemented in each subclass.

Here are description of the fields in each class:
Point has two double fields, x and y. These represent the coordinates on a Cartesian coordinate grid of the point.
Line has two Point fields, p1 and p2. These represent the start and end points of the line.
FreeFormLine has one ArrayList field, points. This represents all of the points along the line.
Circle has one Point field, center, and one double field, radius. These represent the center point of and radius of the circle.

In conclusion, how do I determine which object has more or less value when there is more than one field to evaluate?

Edit:
The purpose of doing this sorting is allow me to search efficiently through an array of DrawingObjects using binary seaching.

Comment: That's something you have to answer. It's too broad - for example it could be based on line length (or circle radius) or the left most point of the line (assuming 2D). There is no general answer.

Comment: I am aware of that. I'm more looking for advice than a concrete answer.

Comment: What does "sorting a list of shapes" even mean? How do we know why you are doing it? Without more information no sensible answer can be given.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you are trying to solve is much harder than ut seems, because you are trying to build a double dispatch method, i.e. a method that is virtual with respect to two objects.

There are ways to do that, for example, using a visitor pattern, but if you would be fine with establishing a fixed order across different classes (say, a point is always less than a rectangle, a rectangle is less than a line, etc.) you could make your code very consistent by making a protected method in your base class that returns the "sort order" for the class:

```
protected abstract int sortOrder();
```

Point would return 0, rectangle would return 1, line would return 2, and so on. Now your comparison method could call sortOrder() on both sides, and decide which one is less than the other if sort ordrrs are not the same.

If sort orders are the same, then the classes are the same. Implement comparable in each class, and forward the call to class-specific comparison method when classes are the same.

As far as comparison of the same class goes, you can decide on an arbitrary ordering among the attributes - say, x before y, height before width, etc. As long as you are consistent about applying your rules, your ordering is going to be fine.